# EF lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Стоит lazy loading в конструкторе контекста (db first)
Когда вытаскиваю запись с базы то вместе с ней приходят все navigation properties которые связаны с этой записью. Вроде как должно работать только в случае если я к этим с свойствам обращаюсь, то тогда подгружать.

Пример:
context.Users.Where(bla bla).FirstOrDefault();

Users.Groups =>> и тут уже подружены данные

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: А как вы определили, что данные загружаются сразу, а не лениво?

Comment: Ну во-первых у связанных данных например не метод Count(),а свойство Count. Тоесть они уже материализованы а не Iquarable

Comment: *не метод Count(),а свойство Count* - чего? При чем тут это? Если вы объявили навигационное свойство как `ICollection` (ну или любой класс, реализующий этот интерфейс), то у него в любом случае есть свойство `Count`. `Count()` же — метод расширения и может использоваться с любыми `IEnumerable` (в том числе и с `ICollection` тоже)

Comment: плохо выразился)  хорошо тогда скажу по-другому. когда возвращаю значение даёт ошибку при сериализации объекта так как свойства бесконечны связаны : User.Groups => Groups.User => User.Grops и так далее.

Comment: Ну это тоже ни о чем не говорит. При обращении `User.Groups` выполняется еще один запрос и данные загружаются. Узнать лениво загружаются данные или нет можно посмотрев генерируемый SQL

Comment: Я не обращаюсь user.Groups.  в это фишка.

Comment: И да,я смотрел sql.

Comment: И что там? Можете пример linq-запроса и пример сгенерированного SQL по нему добавить в вопрос?